# Multiple Camera Capture using Flash or any other web based solution

Tags: html, flash, camera, video-streaming, video-capture

We are in need to capture multiple camera input. We require web based solution in which capture images should be send with other relevant data. I know HTML5 provide camera capture but it always allow single camera at a time.

Please suggest alternate implementation which can work in web.

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried so we don't just repeat suggestions? Did you try using multiple tabs... camera-1 recording in one tab and camera-2 in another tab? Have them both send their video streams to a central server and then the "player" side can choose which stream to watch. I'm no expert on HTML5 webcam video so just an idea to try help yourself while you wait...

Comment: I have used Flash (Flex) to capture multiple cameras at one time.  As long as you specify which camera your attaching, it's fine (although Flash doesn't make it easy to determine which camera is which, but that's another issue...)  One potential problem, if the cameras are on the same USB bus you can have performance issues

Comment: I have just tried HTML5 and it is not possible into that I suppose. I am thinking that it should be possible in Flash. Could you please provide some example link.

Comment: @ManishPansiniya, please use the **@** symbol to notify the person you're addressing, users get auto notification of responses only because it's their Question or Answer. I only saw this cause I decided to check...

Comment: Anyways does the recording part itself have to be done by browser? I mean why not use some desktop software to record from multiple cameras? Then upload all video streams to your broadcast server, and from there, the browser-based viewer can select whichever camera's stream to watch (via button select or drop menu etc). If it has to be recorded by browser then you'll have to start learning AS3 code to make a Flash app... Look up DASH & RTMP streaming formats.

Comment: I am thinking the same but I thought that we need to have different software for Windows/Mac and Linux. Rather than if we can get screenshots using flex, it would be single solution.